# Wordpress get_avatar() $id_or_email

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to create my custom front-end upload of users avatars.

I created form and created custom fields/meta data for it but I have problems with overriding `get_avatar()` wordpress function and I occurred with next problems.

My function can't get userId and size, I tried multiple solutions but I can't find solution why my get_avatar wont accept size and userID or userEmail

Code in **functions.php**

```
add_filter( 'get_avatar' , 'my_get_avatar' );

function my_get_avatar( $user_id, $size = '', $default = '', $alt = false ) {
var_dump($size);

if ( empty( $size ) || ! is_numeric( $size ) ) {
    $size = 96;
}



$custom_avatar = get_user_meta( $user_id, '_user_avatar', true );



if(!($custom_avatar))
{
    $url = "https://webkit.org/demos/srcset/image-src.png";
}
var_dump($custom_avatar);



$html = sprintf('<img src="%s" width="%s" height="%s" class="Avatarmss">', $url, $size,$size);

return $html;


}
```

When I put `var_dump` of `$userID` i get string with img tag and gavatar source

```
<img alt='' src='http://1.gravatar.com/avatar/d10ca8d11301c2f4993ac2279ce4b930?s=32&#038;d=mm&#038;r=g' .....
```

For dumping of size I get empty string.

I found solution.. Every core function is called before **functions.php** so I created custom plugin for this

Answer (score 0):

try

```
add_filter( 'get_avatar','my_get_avatar' , 10, 5 );
```